# Plugin BungeeCord for chat prefix

Tags: plugins, chat, minecraft, prefix, bungeecord

I'm currently developping a bungeecord plugin for my server but It's two days that I'm searching for a problem and any forum have the answer.

**My problem**:

I don't want to create a spigot/bukkit plugin that I have to place in all my server.

My problem is that I want that a player that have a permission like *VelocityPerm.Legend* when he write something on the chat the format is :

PlayerName [LEGEND] What the player write

This is my code :

```java
@EventHandler
public void onChat(ChatEvent e) {
   String line = e.getMessage();
   if(!line.startsWith("/")){
      ProxiedPlayer p = (ProxiedPlayer) e.getSender();
      String message = e.getMessage();
      if(p.hasPermission("VelocityPerm.Founder")) {
         e.setMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[FOUNDER]: " + ChatColor.WHITE + message);
      }
   }
}
```

How to do it ?.

Comment: Thanks Codexis for accepting my edit. It have been rejected because people didn't find the source of the code. I made a discussion about it on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412137/10952503). Hope my edit will help other people, and you will get positive score with your question !

Comment: No problem we are here to help and be help

Comment: Can I ask you a question but in private ?

Comment: What's your discord ?

Comment: Thanks I send you an invites

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a [bungee event](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/event-api/) on your [bungee plugin](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/create-your-first-bungeecord-plugin-proxy-spigotmc/) like that :

```java
@EventHandler
public void onChat(ChatEvent e) {
   ProxiedPlayer p = (ProxiedPlayer) e.getSender();
   if(e.isCommand()) { // check if it's a command, to cancel it or not
      // here you can manage when it's a command.
      // but when we are here, it's NOT a chat message.
   } else { // it's a chat message
      if(p.hasPermission("VelocityPerm.Legend")) { // check if has permission
         e.setMessage("[Legend] " + p.getName() + ": " + ChatColor.WHITE + e.getMessage()); // change message
      }
   }
}
```

Don't forget to register your event :

```java
@Override
public void onEnable() {
   getProxy().getPluginManager().registerListener(this, new MyChatEvent());
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't work, I created the listener Prefix into a package listeners, I copy the code into it, but it's doesn't work.

Comment: You well register the listener ?

Comment: I don't register the event but I do it after.
But the colors don't work, the player name is visible (<name> [founder]: Hello) and the command doesn't work.

Comment: You didn't ask for color. For this you have to check `ChatColor` enum. Also, you never talk about a command So I can't help you for this. If it's a new question, ask a new one :).

Comment: Sorry the command is like /gamemode in game not in the plugin.
My fault I don't explain very good

Comment: You are explaining well, but you didn't give me all informations about it. It's about cancel a command if they don't have permission ?

Comment: I just add one cmd example in my answer, hope it's helpful and reply to your question !

Comment: I rewrite a answer

Comment: Do find an answer to your question ? Also, please edit your question instead of creating a new answer :)